# How to let TF-IDF learn a part of a document with higher priority?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf

I use TfIdf from `sklearn`.

I want to learn similarity between documents. However, these documents contain a title that brings more information than other parts of the documents.

Is it possible to tell TF-IDF that, for instance, if there is a word appears in the title it should be more important than the same word elsewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But you can TFIDF your titles separately and apply a bias calculation to that vector/matrix to boost it before joining it to your other vector/matrix.